# When a row may be linked to many tables... how should I do?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `upload` table, that is a file being uploaded. A file can be liked to a `course`, `news` or `page` (rows of the corresponding tables). A file do not exists without a liked entity, and can be linked to just one (i.e. a page has more uploads, but an upload may be associated to one page at most).

Normally I would define a "base" table `resource` ("child" tables are `course`, `news` and `page` with primary key as foreign key to `resource`), using a foreign key `resource_id` for the `upload` table.

But I can't... I'm using an adjacency list model for `page` and I have to avoid joins. My shared hosting site is really slow at database level, i.e. 1000 ms to perform a query like the following:

```
SELECT 
  r0_.title AS title0, 
  r0_.id AS id1, 
  p1_.slug AS slug2, 
  r2_.title AS title3, 
  r2_.id AS id4, 
  p3_.slug AS slug5, 
  r4_.title AS title6, 
  r4_.id AS id7, 
  p5_.slug AS slug8, 
  r6_.title AS title9, 
  r6_.id AS id10, 
  p7_.slug AS slug11, 
  r0_.type AS type12, 
  r2_.type AS type13, 
  r4_.type AS type14, 
  r6_.type AS type15 
FROM 
  Page p1_ 
  INNER JOIN Resource r0_ ON p1_.id = r0_.id 
  LEFT JOIN Page p3_ ON p1_.id = p3_.parent_id 
  LEFT JOIN Resource r2_ ON p3_.id = r2_.id 
  LEFT JOIN Page p5_ ON p3_.id = p5_.parent_id 
  LEFT JOIN Resource r4_ ON p5_.id = r4_.id 
  LEFT JOIN Page p7_ ON p5_.id = p7_.parent_id 
  LEFT JOIN Resource r6_ ON p7_.id = r6_.id 
WHERE 
  r0_.id = ? 
ORDER BY 
  p3_.position ASC, 
  p5_.position ASC, 
  p7_.position ASC
```

Sum this with 2 or 3 more queries and the time to execute the script itself and you end up with a page load of 5-7 secs. So I dropped the "base" resource table.

How would you link a file to a course, news or page? Maybe just an `integer` column in `upload`?

More on this, as per comment:

When using a resource "base" table, you have to join it with page table. If you are fetching a page at depth of 3 (using the adjacency list model) and want to print out breadcrumbs, you make 3+3 joins with page to get ancestors (and with resource, to get common fields).

Comment: "I have to avoid joins"..."really slow webserver". This makes no sense. How do you propose to link two tables together in a faster way than joins?

Comment: When using a resource "base" table, you have to join it with page table. If you are fetching a page at depth of 3 (using the adjacency list model) and want to print out breadcrumbs, you make 3+3 joins with page/resource.

Comment: I don't know what is the adjacency list model but why don't add a column to course, news and page called resource_id and reference the upload?

Comment: @user1781670 Because a page, course or news may have more than one upload. Sorry if this is not clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

- One is to normalize those tables so you need to create 3 tables: course_uploads, news_uploads and page_uploads, and link a resource with it's uploads.
- And the other option is to create 1 table and to add 4 columns: id, upload_id, resource_type and resource_id.

First model

- Advantage: you can use set up foreign keys to force database
  integrity.
- Disadvantage: queries will be slower.

Second model

- Advantage: you just need to create 1 table.
- Disadvantage: database integrity is up to you.

One more option:
In your uploads table add 2 columns: resource_type and resource_id. And yes, in here database integrity is up to you too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about a resource_id (not FK) in uploads? Integrity up to me...